# Settling error bar default rcParams matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to define a set of functions that set up matplotlib default plotting styles for publication quality figures. I am doing this using the `rc` command (or `matplotlib.rcParams['key'] = value`). I found the list of available options using `matplotlib.rcParams.keys()`. Maybe I am missing something, but it seems that some options are missing for things like `scatter` and `errorbar` plots.

```
from matplotlib import rc, cycler

# DATA GLOBALS
DATA_LINE_COLOR = 'black'
DATA_LINE_STYLE = '-'
DATA_LINE_WIDTH = 0.5
MODEL_LINE_COLOR = 'red'
MODEL_LINE_STYLE = '-'
MODEL_LINE_WIDTH = 0.7

# AXES GLOBALS
AXES_LINE_WIDTH = 0.5
AXES_MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH = 5
AXES_MINOR_TICK_LENGTH = AXES_MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH/2.
AXES_TICK_DIRECTION = 'in'

# FIGURE GLOBALS
ONE_COL_WIDTH = 3.46
TWO_COL_WIDTH = 7.09
DPI = 800

def general():
    """
    General settings for all plot types. Call this first,
    then call any cascading style required
    """
    rc('font', family='Times New Roman', size=10)
    rc('text', color='black')
    rc('figure', dpi=DPI)
    rc('axes',
       xmargin=0.05,
       ymargin=0.05,
       linewidth=AXES_LINE_WIDTH,
       prop_cycle=cycler('color',['black']))
    rc('axes.formatter', limits=(-4, 4))
    rc('xtick', direction=AXES_TICK_DIRECTION)
    rc('xtick.major',
       size=AXES_MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH,
       width=AXES_LINE_WIDTH)
    rc('xtick.minor',
       visible=True,
       size=AXES_MINOR_TICK_LENGTH,
       width=AXES_LINE_WIDTH)
    rc('ytick', direction=AXES_TICK_DIRECTION)
    rc('ytick.major',
       size=AXES_MAJOR_TICK_LENGTH,
       width=AXES_LINE_WIDTH)
    rc('ytick.minor',
       visible=True,
       size=AXES_MINOR_TICK_LENGTH,
       width=AXES_LINE_WIDTH)
```

For example, in the case of `errorbar` there is only one option to adjust, which is `errorbar.capsize`. I would have expected other options such as `errorbar.ecolor` and `errorbar.elinewidth` etc. Is it possible to set these defaults in the rc parameters? Maybe they are inherited from elsewhere?

I know I can set them explicitly on each call to `ax.errorbar` but I want to share a set of functions that set default parameters with colleagues so we can produce coherent figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation to [`plt.errorbar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar), you can see where these values are inherited from.

> `ecolor` : mpl color, optional, default: None
>
> A matplotlib color arg which gives the color the errorbar lines; **if
>   None, use the color of the line connecting the markers.**
>
> `elinewidth` : scalar, optional, default: None
>
> The linewidth of the errorbar lines. **If None, use the linewidth.**
>
> `capthick` : scalar, optional, default: None
>
> **An alias kwarg to markeredgewidth (a.k.a. - mew)**. This setting is a more sensible name for the property that controls the thickness of the error bar cap in points. For backwards compatibility, if mew or markeredgewidth are given, then they will over-ride capthick. This may change in future releases.

So, you should be able to control the colour using the `lines.color` rcParam, the errorbar linewidth using the `lines.linewidth` rcParam, and the cap thickness using the `lines.markeredgewidth` rcParam.

Obviously these may adversely affect other properties in your plots, but I don't think they can be controlled using `rcParams` without also changing those properties.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems strange to link them to the line but then not offer the capability to explicitly set the defaults to be different. If I want to remove the emphasis on the error bars for example (by plotting thin light grey bars and black points), then setting the lines for the error bars will throw off any other lines in the plots. Maybe there is room to improve on this in matplotlib to make it more flexible. I can suggest this in the issue tracker.